# Get the entity of a city given its name and country

Tags: geographics

For example,
input: "Berlin","Germany",
output: something like Entity["City", {"Berlin", "Berlin", "Germany"}]

The reason is, this article,
https://yro.slashdot.org/story/19/09/22/1549223/researchers-determine-the-120-most-surveilled-cctv-cities-in-the-world
its data has name of city and country.
(some names of city may not match those in Mathematica.
for example, the data above has "Washington, D.C.", but Mathematica
uses Entity["City", {"Washington", "DistrictOfColumbia", "UnitedStates"}])

I thought it would be a nice learning experience plotting
this data on a rotating globe,
with a vertical bar normal to the surface of the earth
representing the number of cameras in that city.
Mathematica does not seem to have exactly this,
but GeoBubbleChart is ok.
I need a list similar to the following
Entity["City", {"Berlin", "Berlin", "Germany"}]->39765.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `Interpreter["City"]["Berlin Germany"]` may work for you.

Comment: Will also work for `Interpreter["City"]["Washington, D.C"]`.

Comment: Much thanks!
Interpreter[] works great!
It fails only for two cases:
Interpreter["City"]["Ji'nan, China"]
Interpreter["City"]["Amsterdam,The Netherlands"]

But these two cases have obvious work-arounds:
Get rid of the apostrophe, and the "the"
Interpreter["City"]["Jinan, China"]
Interpreter["City"]["Amsterdam,Netherlands"]

Comment: My procedural program is below.
I know Mathematica programming is supposed to be different than procedural,

Comment: cctvCnt = {}
cities = {}
Do[
 c = i[[1]];
 s = i[[2]];
 c = If[StringMatchQ[c, "Ji'nan"], "Jinan", c];
 s = If[StringMatchQ[s, "The Netherlands"], "Netherlands", s];
 cs = c <> "," <> s;
 x = Interpreter["City"][cs];
 cities = Append[cities,c];
 cnt = i[[3]];
 (* cnt = If[cnt == Null, 1, cnt, cnt]; *)
 cnt = If[cnt == "", 1, cnt];
 cctvCnt = Append[cctvCnt,x->cnt];
 Print[cs, ":", x],
 {i, csv}
]
GeoBubbleChart[cctvCnt, GeoRange -> "World", GeoCenter -> 160, ChartStyle -> 10, BubbleSizes -> {0.005, 0.08}, ChartLabels -> Callout[cities, Automatic]]